# How to emit a string with quotes using yaml-cpp?

Tags: yaml-cpp, emit

I want to emit a string with quotes using yaml-cpp so it looks like

time_stamp: "August 10, 2011 01:37:52"

in the output yaml file. How do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
YAML::Emitter out;
// ...
out << YAML::DoubleQuoted << "August 10, 2011 01:37:52";
```